# (Calling class) from Student import Student getting error that no module named Student

Tags: python

Having a problem getting the module Student to work.

```
def read_file():

    try:

    """Open file for reading"""

    f = open('StudentData.txt', 'r')

    """Read file line by line in a list: readlines()"""

    contents = f.readlines()
    print(contents)

    """Calculate and print number of lines"""

    numOfLInes = len(contents)

    print("Number of lines in the file: {}".format(numOfLInes))

"""Close 
    File"""

    f.close()

except IOError:

    print("File could not be opened")
read_file()
```

class Student(object):
      def **init**(self):
            self.name = 'NoName'
            self.exam1 = 0.0
            self.exam2 = 0.0
            self.finalexam = 0.0
            self.totalScore = 0.0
      def setData(self, name, exam1, exam2, finalexam, totalScore = 0.0):
            self.name = name
            self.exam1 = exam1
            self.exam2 = exam2
            self.finalexam = finalexam
            self.totalScore = totalScore
      def calcFinalScore(self):
            self.totalScore = (self.exam1 + self.exam2 + self.finalexam) / 3
            return self.totalScore

from Student import Student # This line appears to me to be the problem
def write_file():
        try:
               file= open("new.txt", "a")

```
           print("Enter student name")
           name = input()
           print("Enter score for exam 1 (out of 100)")
           e1 = float(input())
           print("Enter score for exam 2 (out of 100)")
           e2 = float(input())
           print("Enter score for final exam (out of 100)")
           final = float(input())
           student1 = Student()
           student1.setData(name,e1,e2,final)

           score = student1.calcFinalScore()

           file.write(name + " " + str(score))

           file.close()
    except:
           print("File could not be opened")
```

write_file()
def read_file():
    try:
        """Open file for reading"""
        f = open('StudentData.txt', 'r')
        """Read file line by line in a list: readlines()"""
        contents = f.readlines()
        print(contents)
        """Calculate and print number of lines"""
        numOfLInes = len(contents)
        print("Number of lines in the file: {}".format(numOfLInes))
        """Close File"""
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print("File could not be opened")
read_file()

Comment: Please try and format your answer in a readable way. Have a clear summary of your problem and what your question is, followed by the code needed

Comment: A few notes: You should use a context manager to handle file objects. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so. `def init(self)` --> `def __init__(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import entities, that you already have in your module. `import` imports something from different modules or packages. Picture this situation:

```
-root_directory
--module1 # contains class Student
--module2 # makes use of class Student
```

To make it work you have to write in `module2` `from module1 import Student` or just `import module1` and use it like this: `module1.Student`. But while your code in one module, you don't have to bother. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Student()` class is in the same module (file), there is no need to import it.

If your `Student()` class is in another module, it will need to be saved in the same directory as the module with your `write_file()` function. It will need to be named `Student.py`

If this is the case, please consider using lowercase names when naming your modules.